# nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed (host not found in upstream)

Tags: nginx, vagrant

I have a vagrant box that has been working fine for sometime and today for some reason I get the following when I attemp to restart nginx.

```
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "www.myclass.com.192.168.33.10.xip.io" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/myclass.com.conf:19
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

I've not changed anything myself as far as I know of (unless Windows Update has done something strange)

Can anyone suggest how to get nginx working again & allowing me to restart the nginx service - it would appear I cannot ping the host... any ideas why?

Here is my nginx conf file:
[nginx conf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwdVy.png)

--Update--
Run the following to check what is on port 80.. (having read another similar post) and I can see that the varnish daemon is on port 80.. is this cause of the problem?? Any advice would be welcomed as I'm new to this stuff

```
sudo netstat -tlnp | grep 80
```

My myclass.com.conf file

```
server {
listen              80;
server_name         class.com.* www.class.com.*;

root /vagrant/www.class.com/public_html;
index index.php;

access_log /vagrant/log/class.com.access.log;
error_log  /vagrant/log/class.com.error.log error;

charset utf-8;

location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

error_page 404 /index.php;

location /socket.io {
    proxy_pass http://www.class.com.192.168.33.10.xip.io:8055;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
}

location / {
    try_files       $uri $uri/ @handler;
    expires         30d;
}

location  /. {
    return 404;
}

location @handler {
    rewrite / /index.php last;
}

location ~ .php/ {
    rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files                       $uri =404;

    expires                         off;

    fastcgi_read_timeout            900;
    fastcgi_index                   index.php;
    fastcgi_pass                    127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param                   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param                   CLASS_ENVIRONMENT LYLE;
    include                         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}

gzip            on;
gzip_min_length 1000;
gzip_proxied    any;
gzip_types      text/plain application/xml text/css text/js application/x-javascript;

sendfile        off;
```

}

Comment: You'll need to post `/etc/nginx/conf.d/myclass.com.conf`  (anything else in `/etc/nginx/conf.d` would help too.

Comment: thanks for commenting - i have added it above now

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All you need is to put resolver that can resolve such domain name:

```
resolver                  8.8.8.8 valid=300s;
resolver_timeout          10s;
```

Google DNS (8.8.8.8) can resolve it, but it resolves to internal address belongs to network class C.

```
$ dig @8.8.8.8 www.class.com.192.168.33.10.xip.io
;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.class.com.192.168.33.10.xip.io. 299 IN A    192.168.33.10
```

Comment: But why does this prevent nginx from starting up properly?

Comment: I don't see a [default resolver server](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver) in configuration. If you use FQDN in proxy_pass you need one.

Comment: @Phil I hope one day some may be able to answer your question. In my case the service no longer exists but I still want to start nginx anyway. it sucks doesn't it?

Answer (score 10):

Your problem is coming from this line:

```
proxy_pass http://www.class.com.192.168.33.10.xip.io:8055;
```

Most likely the server is having difficulty resolving that DNS name.  You may also want to look at https://serverfault.com/questions/341810/nginx-failing-to-resolve-upstream-names-on-reload-even-if-they-do-resolve-by-the

Answer (score 1):

A bit late maybe, but there is a simple solution. Change

```
www.class.com.192.168.33.10.xip.io
```

into

```
www.class.com.192.168.33.10.nip.io
```

and it should resolve on any DNS.